# how do i write multiple function outputs to single csv file

Tags: python-3.x

i am scraping multiple websites so i am using one function for each website script, so each function returns 4 values, i want to print them in dataframe and write them in csv but i am facing this problem, i may be asking something too odd or basic but please help

Either i will have to write whole script in one block and that will look very nasty to handle so if i could find a way around, this is just a sample of problem i am facing..

```
def a1(x):
    z=x+1
    r = x+2
    print(z, r)
def a2(x):
    y=x+4
    t=x+3
    print(y, t)
x = 2
a1(x)
a2(x)

    3 4
    6 5 

data = pd.Dataframe({'first' : [z],
              'second' : [r],
              'third' : [y],
              'fourth' : [t]
               })`
    data

    *error 'z' is not defined*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it convenient to write functions that return a list of dicts.

For example:

```
rows = [dict(a=1, b=2, c=3),
        dict(a=4, b=5, c=6)]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Comment: This is how i am going about it now...def a1(x):
    z=x+1
    r = x+2
    zlist.append(z)
    rlist.append(r)
    print(z, r)
def a2(x):
    y=x+4
    t=x+3
   ylist.append(y)
   tlist.append(t)
    print(y, t)
x = 2
zlist = []
rlist=[]
ylist=[]
tlist=[]
a1(x)
a2(x)

    3 4
    6 5 

data = pd.Dataframe({'first' : zlist,
              'second' : rlist,
              'third' : ylist,
              'fourth' : tlist
               })`[['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']]
    data

Answer (score 0):

The variables are only defined in the local scope of your functions, you'd either need to declare them globally or - the better way - return them so you can use them outside of the function by assigning the return values to new variables

```
import pandas as pd

def a1(x):
    z = x+1
    r = x+2
    return (z, r)

def a2(x):
    y = x+4
    t = x+3
    return (y, t)

x = 2
z, r = a1(x)
y, t = a2(x)

data = pd.DataFrame({'first' : [z],
                  'second' : [r],
                  'third' : [y],
                  'fourth' : [t]
               })
```